# Setting up Redistogo with Django app on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am New to Redistogo:

I have built my project 100% working with Heroku.

I wanted to run few operations on Django Models (Database transactions) after the user input.

Doing these operations takes a bit time and so I decided to run it through a message broker, message queue.

My first preference was using Celery for this but I could not install Celery as requirement on Heroku. It did not identify "Celery-server" as one of my requirement and the push failed.

So as an alternate I started using RedisToGo which is avaialable as an add on to Heroku.

I was able to start the worker and even the messages were being queued to Redistogo, but the jobs were moved to Failed queue. Please find the trace logs below.

```
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675113+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675115+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 789, in perform_job
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675116+00:00 app[worker.1]:     rv = job.perform()
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675118+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 573, in perform
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675119+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._result = self._execute()
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675121+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 579, in _execute
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675123+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675124+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 206, in func
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675126+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return import_attribute(self.func_name)
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675128+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/utils.py", line 152, in import_attribute
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675130+00:00 app[worker.1]:     module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675131+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675133+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675144+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675146+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675147+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675149+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675150+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675152+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675154+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/loginapp/views.py", line 4, in <module>
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675155+00:00 app[worker.1]:     from loginapp.forms import studentmaster, UserForm,studmstform,markattdform,User,firstlastpunch,batchmstform
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675157+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/loginapp/forms.py", line 2, in <module>
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675164+00:00 app[worker.1]:     from django.contrib.auth.models import User
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675166+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675167+00:00 app[worker.1]:     from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675169+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675170+00:00 app[worker.1]:     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675172+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 53, in AbstractBaseUser
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675174+00:00 app[worker.1]:     password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675175+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1061, in __init__
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675177+00:00 app[worker.1]:     super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675178+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675179+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675180+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675181+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._setup(name)
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675183+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675184+00:00 app[worker.1]:     % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675185+00:00 app[worker.1]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
2018-02-12T06:02:19.675186+00:00 app[worker.1]: 06:02:19 Moving job to 'failed' queue
```

As per the error I tried to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` using the command as below.

heroku run `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django.conf.global_settings`

But after this, the heroku app did not start and started throwing error ""`SECRET_KEY` setting must not be empty" when I try to run my app on heroku.

Currently I deleted config variable "`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`" from heroku and the app is working but without any background worker process.

Also kindly advise if it is better to use Redis to go than Celery OR any other better and simple alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Set your config var as follows:

```
heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<value>
```

That sets a [config var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) for your entire app.

Anything you do with "heroku run" only impacts a temporary [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos), and not your entire app.

Comment: Thanks Yoni. I tried that and set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE value to fixed value which appears in my project's settings.py file. After doing this when I try to push the app on heroku, it throws an error: 
     "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <mysecretkey>" and the app crashes.